# MySQL - Sum up slot/shift times per day

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

Let´s assume that we have a kind of shift-scheduler application. You can put users in shifts/timeslots. There is a summary view to show how many hours a person needs to be present at a day in order to fullfill the planned shifts properly (time diff. between min(shift.start) and max(shift.end)). Another value is the SUM of the shifts/timeslots related to a person/day.

Example:

```
Shift 1 | Start: 27.08.2015 08:00 | End: 27.08.2015 10:00
Shift 2 | Start: 27.08.2015 08:00 | End: 27.08.2015 10:00
Shift 3 | Start: 27.08.2015 08:30 | End: 27.08.2015 09:30
Shift 4 | Start: 27.08.2015 10:00 | End: 27.08.2015 11:00
Shift 5 | Start: 27.08.2015 10:30 | End: 27.08.2015 11:30
```

Now it would be easy to SUM up the shifts if a person was only in Shift 1 and Shift 4. That would sum upp to 3 hrs. But if the person was sheduled in all Shifts (1-5) this is not trivial anymore (because of parallel or overlapping timeslots). Now you need to ignore shifts with the same timeslot (shift 1 and 2 are equal, so only one should count) and also shifts that lie in the time of other shifts (like shift 3, thats in the slot of shift 1 and 2). Shift 5 starts in the middle of the timeslot of shift 4 but lasts longer, so only the delta should count.

My question is: Is it possible to calculate the SUM of shifts for a person/day directly in a sql statement (mysql)? A simple SUM for the example above make 7 hrs. But the correct SUM (considering parallel or overlapping shifts etc.) would make 3 hrs and 30 Min. I never found an answer to that question and only got so far to eliminate equal shifts through grouping by shift.start, shift.end or DISTINCT shift.start, shift.end.

This is an example of the query that can sum up and ignores parallel shifts (same timeslots).

```
SELECT

us.idUser, 

CONCAT(SUBSTR(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(sh.end, sh.start)))),1,2),"h ",
SUBSTR(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(sh.end, sh.start)))),4,2),"m") AS sumD

FROM
(

SELECT start, end, id
FROM shift
WHERE (DATE(shift.start) = (SELECT DATE(shift.start) FROM shift WHERE shift.id = 12126))
GROUP BY start, end

) sh

LEFT JOIN user_shift us
ON sh.id = us.idShift

GROUP BY us.idUser
```

There is a table shift that holds all shift information (start, end etc.). Another table is user_shift that holds the idShift and idUser (in which shift is a user scheduled). The query gets a shift.id (12126), fetches the date of that shift to get other shifts of the same day. The Join later matches all shifts of that day to the user IDs. An example result is (idUser: 123 | sumD: 5h 30m).

Comment: You have one person in two shifts at the same Moment?

Comment: Yes, could be. It is more a logical shift structure, not physical :). Parallel shifts are possible.

Comment: Let's not assume anything. Instead, if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

The logic would be:

1. Note the start of the first shift in a table, define your sum.
2. get the next start/end.
3. if the table is empty, add the starttime
4. if it is the end of the first entry in your table, sum up.
5. if it is an end, remove the corresponding start from your table.
6. if it is a start, add it to your table.
7. if your list is not empty, go to 2.

I do not think that is possible to make as one query, and even if possible it is not a easy query to build for that logic, maybe consider to not make it on the sql server.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like a turing machine :-). But the question is if it is possible to get the sum via SQL-query. It is a theoretical question right  now. I´ll try to provide sqlfiddle for that question like Strawberry suggests in his/her comment.